# Is it valid to say that if two wavefunctions are not orthogonal, they must be one and the same?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I'm working on a homework problem that states the following:

[image]

My first thought was that the negative sign would simply add an additional phase of pi to the wavefunction, and hence the two wavefunctions are identical and are not different. I wasn't sure if this is rigorous enough, so I have another approach.

If I calculate the overlap integral for wavefunctions with n = 1 and n = -1, I get -1 as the result. Clearly, the wavefunctions are not orthogonal. **Is this enough to say that the wavefunctions must be identical**, and so we do not speak of two fold degeneracy?

The first issue I have is that I'm not sure if degenerate functions are orthogonal (but I found something about Gram-Schmidt Orthogonalisation), and the second is that the overlap integral gave me -1, while it usually either gives 0 or 1 (the Kronecker Delta) for **well-behaved wavefunctions**. (Perhaps then I can say that the wavefunction I get from n = -1 is not well behaved?)

Any clarification on my assertion that non orthogonality implies identical nature of wavefunctions, as well as any advice on approaching the homework problem, would be much appreciated.

(Note: This is for a First Semester Undergraduate Course, so my knowledge is severely limited)

Comment: If both wave functions are normalized (to unity) and the absolute value of their inner product between both is equal to $1$, then they are linearly dependent. This immediately follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 1):

> the overlap integral gave me -1, while it usually either gives 0 or 1 (the Kronecker Delta) for well-behaved wavefunctions.

What nonzero value you get depends on the relative phases of the two wavefunctions.

> If I calculate the overlap integral for wavefunctions with n = 1 and n = -1, I get -1 as the result. Clearly, the wavefunctions are not orthogonal. Is this enough to say that the wavefunctions must be identical, and so we do not speak of two fold degeneracy?

You need to check whether they are linearly independent. Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization can help you with this. If they are linearly dependent, then after orthogonalization one of the functions will vanish, which would mean the two original functions represent the same state. If they are linearly independent, you'll be able to get two orthogonal functions, in which case you'll be able to speak about degeneracy.

Comment: Thank you! I understood the part about linear independence, but I didn't understand what you mean by "What positive value you get depends on the relative phases of the two wavefunctions." Could you elaborate a bit on that statement please, or maybe give an example? (whichever feels more convenient)

Comment: @poirot_06 consider a wavefunction: $\psi(x),$ and another: $\phi(x)=e^{i\alpha}\psi(x).$ They describe the same state because they differ only by phase. A dot product of them will yield $e^{i\alpha},$ because the dot product of $\psi$ with itself yields $1.$ In your case of $-1$ you have $\alpha=\pi$ (assuming the only difference between the wavefunctions is phase).

Comment: That makes sense. Since you said 'positive value,' does that mean I'm supposed to take the modulus of the overlap integral?

Comment: @poirot_06 oh, this is my mistake, I meant nonzero, not necessarily positive.

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't. Not being orthogonal just means their inner product is nonzero. However, consider for example the Cartesian vectors $\hat{x}$ and $(\hat{x}+\hat{y})/\sqrt{2}$, which are both unit vectors. Their overlap is $1/\sqrt{2}$, which is nonzero. But they clearly are not the same vector! Having a nonzero overlap only means that two unit vectors (or quantum states or wave functions) are not *orthogonal*. **For the wave functions to be equal, their overlap must be one, not merely nonzero.**

So if $\int {\rm d}x \, \psi^* (x) \varphi(x) \neq 0$ means the two wavefunctions are not orthogonal, while $\int {\rm d}x \, \psi^* (x) \varphi(x) =1$ means they are the same. The only caveat I'll add is that if two **basis fuctions** (or vectors) are not orthogonal, they are the same, but that is by definition of basis vectors (they are all mutually orthogonal).